# JS Умножение двух рандомных цифр и вывод в отдельном span

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы 2 рандомных числ, записанных в span, умножались и выдавали в другом span ответ. Сейчас вместо ответа выводится NaN

```js
var numberDisplayFirst = document.querySelector("#numberdisplayfirst");
    var numberDisplaySecond = document.querySelector("#numberdisplaysecond");
    var amountDisplay = document.getElementById("amountDisplay");

    numberDisplayFirst.textContent = randomNumberFirst();
    numberDisplaySecond.textContent = randomNumberSecond();
    amountDisplay.textContent = SumNumbers();

    function randomNumberFirst(min = 1, max = 10) {
            var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
            rand = Math.round(rand);
            return rand;
          }
        
    function randomNumberSecond(min = 1, max = 10) {
            var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
            rand = Math.round(rand);
            return rand;
          }
       
    function SumNumbers(randomNumberFirst, randomNumberSecond) {
            var sum = randomNumberFirst*randomNumberSecond;
            return sum;
          }
```

```html
<h1>
          <span id="numberdisplayfirst"></span>
           x 
          <span id="numberdisplaysecond"></span>
           = 
          <span id="amountDisplay"></span>
        </h1>
```

Comment: `SumNumbers()` - здесь вы не передаете значения при вызове.

Comment: Я заменила у себя amountDisplay.textContent = SumNumbers() на amountDisplay.textContent = SumNumbers(randomNumberFirst, randomNumberSecond), но всё равно не считает.

Comment: @АннаЧередниченко И совет от меня. Используйте let а не var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас одна функция используется множество раз.
Я на вашем месте писал бы так:

```js
let numberDisplayFirst = document.getElementById("numberdisplayfirst");
let numberDisplaySecond = document.getElementById("numberdisplaysecond");
let amountDisplay = document.getElementById("amountDisplay");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
let secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);

numberDisplayFirst.textContent = firstNumber;
numberDisplaySecond.textContent = secondNumber;
amountDisplay.textContent = firstNumber * secondNumber;
```

```html
<h1>
  <span id="numberdisplayfirst"></span>
  <span>x</span>
  <span id="numberdisplaysecond"></span>
  <span>=</span>
  <span id="amountDisplay"></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Правда, это не невнимательность. Я всего месяц назад начала учить JS, устроила для себя челледж написать математическую игру в браузере. Часть непонятных мне тем ищу в интернете, а часть приходится тут спрашивать. Но перед этим я всегда по много часов сижу. пытаясь сама додуматься :)

Comment: Почему это невнимательность? о_О Мне кажется, это незнание, как работают функции. Возможно, незначние областей видимости.

Comment: @АннаЧередниченко посмотрите ещё раз на ответ. Снизу я показал вам правильный подход.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko ещё раз спасибо) К сожалению, мне совсем не у кого спрашивать, потому что я самоучка, а не студентка. И каждый раз, когда задаю вопросы на форумах, чувствую, будто недостаточно постаралась и не сама нашла ответ. Но теперь благодаря вам я знаю чуть больше. В частности, что переменные нельзя приравнивать к функциям :)